# Scope issue with passing function as parameter

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

After I instantiate my class, I call `myClass.testScope()`, which calls another function inside the class. But, when I pass the function as a parameter, I lose scope and calling `testScopeFromPassedParam` from `data1` results in the error ***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'testScopeFromPassedParam'***

Can someone please aid in the best way to handle this?

http://jsfiddle.net/2sJVX/4/

```
class MyClass

  test: () ->

    @testScope()

  testScope: () ->

    console.log 'worky'

  testScopeFromPassedParam: () ->

    console.log 'no worky'

  data1: (cb) ->

    # Shoot. The error.
    @testScopeFromPassedParam()

    setTimeout (->
      cb '1'
    ), 1000

  data2: (cb) ->
    setTimeout (->
      cb '2'
    ), 3000

  loadData: () ->

    getDeferred = (someFunction) ->

      deferred = $.Deferred()

      someFunction (data) ->

        console.log data

        deferred.resolve()

      deferred

    dataFunctions = [
      @data1
      @data2
    ]

    arrayOfPromises = [ ]
    for someFunction in dataFunctions
      arrayOfPromises.push getDeferred(someFunction)

    $.when.apply(null, arrayOfPromises).done () =>
      alert 'returned'

myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.testScope()
myClass.loadData()
```

Comment: Usually that sort of thing is handled by creating a reference in a closure scope, but not sure how such a solution would work in coffeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not [variable] scope, that's the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) which is lost here. You will need to bind the function to your object, in coffeescript you can use the [fat-arrow syntax](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) for this:

```
data1: (cb) =>
    @testScopeFromPassedParam()
    …
```

Btw, you really should pass on the `data` to the resolve function (or just use `somefunction deferred.resolve`)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, terminology was wrong. Can you explain what you mean by "I really should pass on the data to the resolve function", please? I'm missing it :)

Comment: You call `deferred.resolve()` with nothing, but you should do `deferred.resolve(data)` otherwise the promise doesn't get the value :-)

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. This exercise was really about learning about $.when and deferreds, then I ran into this issue. Thanks!